# event.currentTarget.files doesn't work on React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to upload files through input file using React Typescript.

I have this piece of code inside a Component

```
<div className="col-6">
  <label htmlFor="">Logo</label>
  <input className='form-control-file' onChange={this.handleChange('imagen')} type="file"/>
</div>
```

The method `onChange` contains the following line codes:

```
public handleChange = (clave: string) => {
  return (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
     e.preventDefault()
     if (clave === 'imagen') {
       alert(e.currentTarget.files) // Also tried e.target, but this is undefined
     }
   })
}
```

But this simply shows `undefined`. I am looking for someone with the same problem but I can't found nothing, and this makes me think that it should be a very stupid thing, but I am new on Typescript and I can't find out the solution.

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get this works by simply adding

```
    public handleChange = (clave: string) => {
        return (e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            ...
        }
    }
```

That way I can access to `target` key, and `target.files` also.